How to use an import in a try and catch
I am currently creating a development dashboard that allows users to swap between environments. I am storing these environment keys using a environment.js file that stores each environment as JSON.
This is currently working perfectly and is not causing any errors. My only issue is that my build is failing if the environments file is not present. is there a way I can stop the build from failing in some way.
let environments = {};
try {
    // @ts-ignore
    environments = await import("@/environments");
} catch (error) {}


Your suggested try/catch block looks fine, and in my tests it works.
That said, you did have to use a // @ts-ignore because the file doesn't always exist, and ESM dynamic imports and top-level await are both kinda tricky features that won't work in all environments and configurations, so you may want to consider using fs.existsSync, fs.readFileSync and JSON.parse instead.
(You'll probably also need path.join to get the path to your environments file in a platform-agnostic way, cause path delimiters are different across operating systems.)
So that might look like this:
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs";

const getEnvironments = () => {
  // amend this to be wherever your file is
  const path = path.join(__dirname, "environments"); 
  
  if (!existsSync(path)) return {};


  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, "utf-8"));
};

const environments = getEnvironments();

Note:

you could add try/catches around a lot of bits of that, but if any part of it fails you probably want startup to fail
you may need to do some additional type casting to strongly type the environments object

